# Do TCP/UDP connections add to the Windows incoming connection limit?

Tags: windows-xp

I've tried to figure out what Microsoft means by "Windows sockets" and it all seems very vague. Basically we have customers that sometimes try to set up workgroups with close to 10 Windows XP computers with drive and printer shares and we're worried that some of the non-Windows Ethernet devices on the network will cause issues with the inbound connection limit outlined [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882) where only 10 inbound connections can be active at one time.

For example, there is an Ethernet Caller ID device that broadcasts UDP packets to all computers, and a kitchen display system that likewise broadcasts UDP. They may also have incoming TCP packets for our custom online ordering module.  Do these TCP/UDP connections count toward the inbound connection limit?

I'm aware that Windows 7 has increased the limit to 20 but we might have future customers that will push that limit.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A Windows Socket is basically the same concept as [Berkley Sockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berkeley_sockets). Those have absolutely nothing to do with the 10 Connection limit you're looking at. The 10 Connection limit is an unenforced application session limit. Basically this is to prevent people from abuse XP as a public web server platform, file server, or something similar.

Comment: It is enforced though, right? An 11th shared folder connection would be denied wouldn't it?

Comment: @Joe, some things are enforced, like the shared folder connections, but the list is very short.