# Inbound TCP connection limit in Windows 7, according to the license

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, tcp, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

According to the license agreement for Windows 7:

> You may allow up to 20 other devices to access software installed on
>   the licensed computer to use only File Services, Print Services,
>   Internet Information Services and Internet Connection Sharing and
>   Telephony Services.

Since it doesn't mentioned 3rd party TCP connections I assume that Microsoft now allows "unlimited" inbound connections?

It didn't used to: see this Microsoft article about [Inbound connections on XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882).

I ask because for our software can accept many TCP connections (from other instances of our software), and we don't want to break any license agreements by doing so.

Comment: Interesting how this question is closed because it contains the words `license` and `licensing`, yet the 2nd link in TheCleaner's answer, which is essentially the same question, doesn't get closed because the question avoids using the words `license` or `licensing`.

Comment: We're online, we don't need to be polite! I thought the point of these communities is that they're ... well ... communal? Ring your Mums and see how they would respond to such a question. Perhaps something like "Sorry, licensing questions can't be answered because they're too complicated"

Answer (score 0):

This has been answered before:

https://superuser.com/questions/253141/inbound-tcp-connection-limit-in-windows-7

[Do TCP/UDP connections add to the Windows incoming connection limit?](https://serverfault.com/questions/234131/do-tcp-udp-connections-add-to-the-windows-incoming-connection-limit)

The limit is 20 if you do a "net config server" from a cmd prompt you will see this as well.